# How to set the default umask in Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, umask

How can I set the default umask for Arch Linux. I need 0022 but the default is 0027 on my system. I checked `etc/profile/` and it says

```
umask 0022
```

But somewhere another value for umask gets set and I can't find it. Any suggestions where the 0027 umask could be set or where I can override it?

Comment: Did you check the obvious places, like *.bashrc* in your own directory, or */etc/bashrc*?

Comment: Yes, `/etc/bashrc` is empty. Just now I found out that if I add umask 0022 to `~/.bashrc` I can overwrite the default. But I still don't know why it defaults to 0027.

Comment: Did you try */etc/fstab*?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae There is no *umask* entry in my `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the `umask 027` statement in my `~/.profile` file. Commenting it and uncomment `umask 022` fixed it.

### ~/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
umask 022
# umask 027
```